# Landsat 8 Cloud Cover

Tags: arcgis-desktop, landsat-8, cloud-cover

I downloaded Landsat 8 imagery from Earth Explorer for a particular area.  I tried to get it with no cloud cover, but it did not show any results.  The least amount of cloud cover that I could get was 40%.  Is there a way that I can remove the cloud cover in ArcGIS for Desktop 10.5?  I have seen script on how to do it but I cannot figure out how to do it in ArcMap.  Does anyone know how you can remove cloud cover from Landsat imagery in ArcMap?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292835/landsat-8-bqa-using-cloud-confidence-to-create-a-cloud-mask

Comment: This link looks like it just shows script but it does not say anything in ArcMap.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: The link you've posted is for scripting in Google Earth Engine. There are great cloud identifying tools there, but you'd need to traverse the learning curve. Landsat 8 imagery has a quality band (Band 9) that contains cloud information. You can use this band + raster calculator to make a mask of cloudy pixels, but I'll let you figure out the details.